# Cython implementation of python code - finding major problems preventing speed gain

Tags: optimization, cython

I have been trying to use Cython to speed up a code in which the attached function is the main workhorse. However, my results have been very unsatisfactory: after trying very hard (but most likely not in a smart way) I have been only able to get around a 5-10% increase in speed. I feel there is something basic I have missed here; please help out.

My original implementation of the code used eigenvalue decomposition for matrix exponential/power (my custom function), which gave it some boost. I wonder however doing that here would be beneficial or not.

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
cdef t_routine(float complex[:,:] Uv , float complex [:,:] UBAv , float complex [:,:] UBA1v , float complex [:,:] rhov , int j): #Fixed t routine.
    hda = np.empty(tmax-tmin, dtype = typf) #f = float, #c  = float complex
    cdef float[:] hdv = hda

    cdef int ta,b,a, size = 2*j+1
    cdef float hd, p, q, sum 

    UA = np.linalg.matrix_power(Uv, ta) 
    UA1 = UA.conj().T 
    cdef float complex [:,:] UAv = UA
    cdef float complex [:,:] UA1v = UA1

    UB = sp.matmul(UBAv, UAv)
    UB1 = UB.conj().T
    cdef float complex [:,:] UBv = UB
    cdef float complex [:,:] UB1v = UB1

    rhoA = sp.matmul( sp.matmul(UAv, rhov), UA1v)   #scipy
    rhoB = sp.matmul(sp.matmul(UBv, rhov) , UB1v)   
    cdef float complex [:,:] rhoBv = rhoB 
    cdef float complex [:,:] rhoAv = rhoA

    PB = np.empty(size, dtype=typf)
    PC = np.empty(size, dtype=typf)
    cdef float [:] PBv = PB
    cdef float [:] PCv = PC  

    I = np.identity(size, dtype=typc)
    cdef float complex [:,:] Iv = I 




    for ta in range(tmin, tmax+1):    

        for b in range(size):
            BP = np.outer(Iv[:,b], Iv[b,:])  
            PBv[b] = Prob(BP, rhoBv, size)
            sum = 0
            for a in range(size):
            #   Aket = JZket(j,b)
                AP = np.outer(Iv[:,a], Iv[a,:]) 
                p = Prob(AP, rhoAv, size)
                rhoC = sp.matmul(sp.matmul(UBAv, AP), UBA1v )
                q = Prob(BP, rhoC, size)
                sum = sum+p*q
            PCv[b] = sum
        hd = HD(PBv, PCv)
        hdv[ta] = hd
    return hda
```

Comment: So have you tried the html annotation tool to identify which code is still basically python?  I'm seeing a lot of use of `matmul` which already uses a fast compiled library.

Comment: Yes. I have used it; This function has yellow all over it. Only a few lines which are really not calling any python objects are white (such as PBv[b] = sum towards the end).  I have my naive matmul written in C, and I tested it against sp.matmul, after which I used the latter here. But I'm wondering because its a "cdef" function whether that is a good thing or not?